# Python's Pytest.mark equivalent for non-test code

Tags: python, pytest, decorator

The Pytest testing framework has this nice feature, where you can [mark](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html) tests with certain attributes, for example:

```py
import pytest
@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_startup():
   pass
```

Then, using the `pytest` command line, you can preform actions only on functions/tests with certain marking:
i.e: `pytest -m webtest` will only run `webtest` marked code. There are also command line to query all the tests with certain marker, etc.

My question is, is there an equivalent library which does this for just regular code? For example:

```py
@mark.refactor
def foo():
   pass

# Or #
@mark.todo("Specifying a todo comment which can be grammatically queried later")
def bar():
   pass
```

Then I could run a command line or script to get all the functions marked `todo` or `refactor` and get their info.

I tried to look online but couldn't find any matching libraries for this use case.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a functionality you want that couldn't be covered by something simple like using comments and `grep`?

Comment: I could use grep and mark functions using comments, but: A. it is not platform agnostic, B. hard to add metadata to the results (line number, function name, commiter, filename, last modified etc')

Comment: regarding running only tests with a specific marker, the Django framework has a `tag` decorator (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#tagging-tests) but you probably wouldn't want to use a complete framework just for this functionality...

Answer (score 0):

After I couldn't find any answers, A buddy of mine wrote a python library that achieves this.

It is available [here](https://github.com/yeger00/markings) on github.

For example:

```
@marker.todo("still need to figure this out")
def func():
    print("hello world")

@marker.known_issue
def func2():
    print("hello world")
```